# How to create microfrontend single page application(In angular) with specific version

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, single-spa-angular

I am new to microfrontend. I have created the microfrontend angular application(Using single SPA approach) using the command "create-single-spa", project is created with latest version i.e 15.1.0. But I want to create project with the specific version i.e.12.0.0. Can anyone help me. Is there any commands to create microfrontend singl SPA application with specific version.

Comment: I've never used `create-single-spa` but can you tell us how you can tell the version is 15.1.0? Does it pop up in the console or show up in a config file or is it returned as response to a CLI command?